# Need batch command for pandoc

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pandoc

I have a directory with sub directories in it and i am trying to convert docx into html.
So far i have found this command:

```
@ECHO off
:selectfile
:: Clear any preexisting filename variables
SET filename=
:: Ask which file we're converting.
SET /p filename=Which file? (Don't include the .docx file extension):
CALL pandoc -o -s "%filename%".html --self-contained "%filename%".docx
GOTO selectfile
```

The problem is its asking me for the file names and i have to put this bat file inside every subfolder to do the job.
I want to make some changes so that it will detect subfolders automatically and convert all the docx files into html files with the same name.
Is this possible guys?
Can anyone modify this script?
thanks really appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3695/for-loops-in-batch-files#t=201703061006249850917

Comment: And please enclose entire file names in double quotes and not just parts of it forcing Windows command interpreter respectively the startup code of the started application to fix the parameter string, i.e. use `"%filename%.html"` and `"%filename%.docx"`.

Comment: set filename command will mess this up. its fine and working like this but not solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commented code snippet could help:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem iterate all *.docx recursively
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S *.docx  2^>NUL') do (

    rem check .html existence
    if not exist "%%~dpnG.html" (

        rem change the current directory and store the previous path for use by the POPD
        pushd "%%~dpG"

        rem `CALL pandoc` is merely displayed for debugging purposes
        rem               remove ECHO no sooner than debugged          
        ECHO CALL pandoc -o -s "%%~nG.html" --self-contained "%%~nxG"

        rem change directory back to the path most recently stored by the PUSHD command
        popd
    )
)
```

**Edit**

> I want to make some changes so that it will **detect subfolders
>   automatically** and **convert all** the `docx` files into `html` files
>   with the same name.

You could embed above code snippet to your script as follows:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:selectfile
:: Clear any preexisting filename variables
SET filename=
:: Ask which file we're converting.
SET /p filename=Which file? (Don't include the .docx file extension):

if not defined filename GOTO selectfile

rem iterate all %filename%.docx recursively
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S "%filename%.docx" 2^>NUL') do (
    rem check .html existence
    if not exist "%%~dpnG.html" (
        rem change the current directory and store the previous path for use by the POPD
        pushd "%%~dpG"
        rem `CALL pandoc` is merely displayed for debugging purposes
        rem               remove ECHO no sooner than debugged          
        ECHO CALL pandoc -o -s "%%~nG.html" --self-contained "%%~nxG"
        rem change directory back to the path most recently stored by the PUSHD command
        popd
    )
)

GOTO selectfile
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory) getting this error.

Comment: its searching all sub folders tho..@JosefZ

Comment: Just removed -s and worked.. thanks a ton. man really appreciate this :D